# VB.NET Gecko Web Browser javascript function calling?

Tags: javascript, vb.net, web, browser, gecko

I am using `GeckoWebBrowser` within my `VB.NET` (Windows Form App) program. The `GeckoWebBrowser` loads a local `html` file. This `html` has embed in-line a `svg` file ([human body diagram with bones and internal organs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z19NK.png)) with a `javascript` function for picking up all the "ids" of the elements from the `svg` document. I'd like to call the aforementioned `javascript` function from `VB.NET` (Windows form app), but I don't know how to do so. Can anyone help me, or give me a source code example please? All the stuff I've found is based in `C#`...
This is my `javascript` function in my `html` file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

(funcion () {

// Function to be called in VB.NET when the DOM is loaded


var SVGHandler = function () {

    // Picking up the id Root Node="CUERPO_HUMANO" into svg variable

    var svg = document.querySelector('#CUERPO_HUMANO');


    // In Items we save all the <g> which have an ID

    var items = svg.querySelectorAll('g[id], path[id]');

    //var items = svg.querySelectorAll('g[id]');

    // We loop all the nodes saved in Items and add them to click event listener 

    forEach(items, function (index, value) {

        value.addEventListener('click', function (event) {



                event.preventDefault();

                //We avoid the spread of events
                event.stopPropagation();





                return event.currentTarget.id

                // console.log(event.currentTarget.id)

            });

    });



}

// https://toddmotto.com/ditch-the-array-foreach-call-nodelist-hack/

var forEach = function (array, callback, scope) {

  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

    callback.call(scope, i, array[i]); // passes back stuff we need

  }

};



// With this method, we call a SVGHandler when DOM is totally loaded 

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', SVGHandler);

})();

</script>
```

What code should I use in `VB.NET` for calling my `javascript` function each time I click on a specific bone or organ in the human body diagram loaded in `GeckoWebBrowser`?
I want to save the "id" picked up with the calling into a `string` variable in order to use it as a parameter in a `SQL` statement and populate a `DataGridView`.
I've been searching and all that I could find was related to `C#`, not a single `VB.NET` example. Even though I was trying to figure out the equivalence in `VB.NET` trying to convert the `C#`'s examples to `VB.NET`, I have some doubts on how to do the `javascript` call. According to my `javascript` function It could be something like this:

```
browserControl.Navigate("javascript:void(funcion())");
```

Please, Can anyone help me to solve this? I would be very thankful...

Answer (score 1):

Well since you have set click `EventListener`'s I think that you're not looking for a way to call the eventual function from `VB.NET` but this is quite unclear according to your post so I'll give you examples on how to call a `javascript` function and how to trigger a reaction in your `VB.NET` code through `javascript` using `GeckoWebBrowser`.

Your code snippet of your attempt to call a js function from your vb code is correct. The only problem is that you haven't defined any callable js function in your `html` file. In your case you should do this to trigger your main js function from vb:

```
//Sorry I don't know vb. I'll give example in c# keeping it as simple as possible so that you can easily convert it to vb

Gecko.GeckoHtmlElement humanBodyPart = (Gecko.GeckoHtmlElement) browserControl.Document.GetElementById("your id");
humanBodyPart.Click();
```

The above code finds the element with the matching id in the `GeckoWebBrowser` and clicks it. Since you've set click `EventListener`'s, by clicking one of the elements this will trigger the function assigned to them to run.

Moving on, in order to save the id of the elements to a `string` variable in your vb code you'll need to add this little bit of js code in to the code that you pass as 'callback' parameter in your `forEach` function:

```
var event = document.createEvent('MessageEvent');
var origin = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host;
var event = new MessageEvent('jsCall', { 'view': window, 'bubbles': false, 'cancelable': false, 'data': 'YOUR EVENTUAL ID AS A STRING (THIS STUFF GOES BACK TO THE VB/C# CODE)' });
document.dispatchEvent (event);
```

Then the above snippet should be handled in your vb code like this:

```
browserControl.AddMessageEventListener("jsCall", (id) =>
{
   //Here in the variable id you have your clicked id as a string. Do what you wanted to do...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

VB side : 
you need wait until the document is completed to add listeners
for example : _DocumentCompleted

`Private Sub GeckoWebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As Gecko.Events.GeckoDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles GeckoWebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
        GeckoWebBrowser1.AddMessageEventListener("my_function_name JS_side", AddressOf my_sub_for_treatment)
    End Sub`

JS side :

```js
var event = document.createEvent('MessageEvent');
var origin = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host;
var event = new MessageEvent('my_function_name JS_side', { 'view': window, 'bubbles': false, 'cancelable': false, 'data': my_data_to transfer });
document.dispatchEvent (event);
```